# React-Native assets not loading - errors not clear

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I am using React-native along with AWS Amplify and AWS AppSync with GraphQL. When I load my app in the ios simulator with the command `npx react-native ios` the app loads, but it is not loading the assets.

If I inspect and click on something like `App` or `Navigator` I get the following errors. I'm not sure if they are related. I had this working and without changing any code this started happening.

Here is an example of how I'm trying to load an asset:

> <TouchableOpacity
> style={styles.write}
> onPress={() => this.toggleWritePopup()}>
> <Image source={require('../assets/writeicon.png')} />

[image: error in simulator from inspect element]

Edit:
Here is the output for `react-native info`

```
System:
OS: macOS 10.15.6
CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7267U CPU @ 3.10GHz
Memory: 6.88 GB / 16.00 GB
Shell: 5.7.1 - /bin/zsh
 Binaries:
Node: 12.18.3 - /usr/local/bin/node
Yarn: Not Found
npm: 6.14.6 - /usr/local/bin/npm
Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
Managers:
CocoaPods: 1.9.3 - /usr/local/bin/pod
SDKs:
iOS SDK:
  Platforms: iOS 14.0, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 14.0, watchOS 7.0
Android SDK: Not Found
IDEs:
Android Studio: Not Found
Xcode: 12.0/12A7209 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
Java: 12.0.1 - /usr/bin/javac
Python: 2.7.16 - /usr/bin/python
npmPackages:
@react-native-community/cli: Not Found
react: 16.9.0 => 16.13.1
react-native: ^0.62.2 => 0.63.3
react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
*react-native*: Not Found
```

Edit:
This is another section of code where this png is also not loading. So even with the dimensions it does not work:

```
 <ImageBackground
      source={require('../assets/blue_ocean.png')}
      style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>
```

Comment: Can you add the code? How are you trying to load the assets?

Comment: Sure I'll add. Like I said I don't believe the code is the issue since I started a brand new clone of the repo that I can confirm is working with some other people.

Comment: have you linked the assets to the project? using `npx react-native link`

Comment: @Glitch_Znab I ran that command, but it did not fix my problem. I should clarify that these are simply my own .png's in my project that I am trying to load.

Comment: If I am not wrong every asset has to be linked the project for it to show up which was a real headache during my project which is why I stopped using assets entirely. Can you also follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/64117872/12370254 after linking because it might not be showing up because of cache

Comment: I’m not able to follow a lot of the steps. I get an error for any of those gem commands.

Comment: Please add more info: RN version, Xcode version, iOS version of the simulator

Comment: @FlorinDobre added

Comment: Does the code works for images with uri like this:      ` <Image
        style={styles.tinyLogo}
        source={{
          uri: 'https://reactnative.dev/img/tiny_logo.png',
        }}
      /> `?

Comment: Add more code pls, the issue doesn't look related to assets. And the code is missing the closing tag for TouchableOpacity.

Comment: I have people with identical code who don’t have this issue.

Comment: 1) Try to add some width, height, to the image and a flex: 1 to the container. 2) try to display an image from and uri. If that works then it's an issue with the assets (not linked or bad location). Let me know if you can display an image from uri and what happens if you add some measures to the image.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok I finally figured it out. It was the iOS version that was running in the simulator. For whatever reason my code doesn't seem to work for iOS 14.0. If I set it to a earlier version my assets load with no issue.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this a while back and in my case the errors were because the `reactNode` sent to the `scrollToFocusedInput` were `null`.

Trace/debug the `scrollToFocusedInput` method and/or do a `console.log(event, reactNode)`.

This could have been caused because you did not use the default SDK install path or because the JS bundle is referred to your dev machine rather than the local device.

If you are running on emulator, make sure the emulator has default settings and access to the emulated baseband (cellular turned on). Turning stuff off on emulator can cause weird build behavior.

Comment: Ok so I reset the simulator settings, and I'm still having the issue. How do I check my SDK path and JS bundle reference?

Comment: Can you redo the react-native installer command or do an update on it? It's very likely that is where this is wrong, since your code apparently does work on new instances

Comment: I ran `npx react-native upgrade` and unfortunately the problem persists.

Comment: Did you follow these steps? https://medium.com/@abhisheknalwaya/how-to-clear-react-native-cache-c435c258834e

Comment: Looking at xcode then; can you try this? https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29984#issuecomment-695990883